# Update Chart When New Row Of Data Is Added

Tags: excel, vba, rows, excel-charts

I'm working on macro that will refresh the chart when new information is added to the data sheet and When video or filter dime rows

However, anytime I add a new row to the data sheet, the chart format WAS WRONG. PLEASE HELP ME :( .Here is my code:

```
Sub RangeRefresh()
 Dim vAddress As range, n As Long, c As range
 Dim lastRow
 lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1)
 Set vAddress = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",B2:B" & lastRow)

        n = 0 'for counting visible datapoints

    For Each c In vAddress.Cells

       'is the row visible? skip if not
       If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden Then
       n = n + 1 'next visible datapoint
       End If                            
   Next 
   End Sub
```

Comment: No need for VBA. You can use a [dynamic named range](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) and base the chart formula on that range.

Comment: Thanks but i'm need work with VBA, the range constantly will change, a botton to running the code will be help me a lot. but thank!!

Comment: *the range constantly will change* - that is the purpose of using dynamic named ranges. the will adjust for any data that changes the range boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to catch exactly what do you mean by "the chart format WAS WRONG" so I hope I'm correct with this answer.

Please have a look on this ressource, you can find further help there :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.seriescollection

I think you can adapt the

```
Charts("chart1").SeriesCollection.Add _
   source:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:a19")
```

To something like

```
Charts("chart1").SeriesCollection.Add _
    source:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A"& lastRow)
Charts("chart1").SeriesCollection.Add _
    source:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B"& lastRow)
```

I hope it will work !
Take care

Comment: "I'm not sure what you mean" and "I think you can" is not an answer. If you have conditions you need clarified in order to provide an answer, then please post them as a comment for the question instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information, I take note for the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

so, this is the code when the range constantly will change:

```
Sub RefreshRange()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng1 As range
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng1 = .range("A2:A" & LastRow & ", B2:B" & LastRow)
End With

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
End With
```

End Sub